# How to send sms notification to Users through Android App

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-notifications, android-sms

I am working on an Online Booking Android App. I want to send notification to the users who confirm their Booking on my application. I am using Firebase for my app. I exactly want the text message that we got from various other apps like this:-

[image]

What I am getting through searching on the Internet is :-How to send notification, how to send sms through your app, how to send multiple sms through your app. Firebase in also providing Cloud messaging services. But what I understand from there is about How to send sms through Firebase to multiple users. 
I just want to send confimation sms to the user's who registered mobile number with my app on some specific actions by them. How I can do the same. Do I need to code in Android Studio or on server.
Also these messages that we got from companies are in notification section rather than simple sms. Can I do the same in through App. And the number they are using for sms also seems to be different. I don't know how they are doing it. As you can understand I am totally new in this area. Your little suggestion can help.

Comment: Basically this message should be sent from server, but you can also use third party text message api's to trigger text messages from your android app too (only when this booking is confirmed)

Comment: I am using Firebase for back-end services. Can I use the same for sending messages notification.

Comment: You can use firebase for sending verification sms but cannot send ordinary sms. You can try Twilio instead for sending ordinary sms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio's Programmable SMS API helps you add robust messaging capabilities to your applications.

```
link=
 https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/php
```